# Don't show get parameter in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In My route:

```
Route::get('/item/{itemId?}', 'ItemController@index');
```

Controller returning to:

```
http://example.com/item/12
```

But in blade don't showed `{{Request::segment(3);}}`

Please, help! And sorry for my English

Comment: {Request::segment(2);}} :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `segment(2)`:

```
{{ Request::segment(2) }}
```

And `segment(1)` will return "item"

Answer (score 1):

Your route has 2 segments! so if you need id it's in segment2

```
{{ Request::segment(2) }}
```

segment 1 will be equal to items

```
 {{ Request::segment(1) }} //items
```